# Checkbox click works 2 times

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I tried to show everything on the demo video.

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/github/b1gun0v/reactjs-typescript-vladilen-minin

Demo: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xt032rjyXsU

Comment: () => onToggle(todo.id)

Comment: Thanks, but it did not help.

Comment: All code relevant to the question must be included here on Stack Overflow, not only on an external site. You may be able to use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to produce a runnable snippet here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Yeah.  What Gavin said should help. But you should really output the code right here and show us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It helps you
1) use this approach when you want to update a state

```
const toggleHandler = (id: number) => {
    const newObject = todos.map(x => {
      if (x.id === id) {
        x.completed = !x.completed;
      }
      return x;
    });
    setTodos(newObject);
  };
```

...

```
  const addHandler = (title: string) => {
    const newTodo: ITodo = {
      title: title,
      id: Date.now(),
      completed: false
    };
    // setTodos([newTodo, ...todos])
    setTodos([newTodo, ...todos]);
  };
```

2) do not foget clear storage when component unmount

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const saved = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todos") || "[]") as ITodo[];
    setTodos(saved);

    return () => {
      localStorage.removeItem("todos");
    };
  }, []);
```